# Using multi variables in function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use multiple variables in a function. This one works for 2 variables, but what if there are 5 sites to get scripts from?

```
function scripts(url,url2){
            window.setInterval(function (){
                $.getScript(url);
                $.getScript(url2);
                        },10000)
        }

scripts('http://www.site1.com/1.jpg','http://www.site2.com/1.jpg');
```

What is the correct way to use multiple variables in a function, when we can use as more variables as we can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an unknown number of variables you can do it two ways.

1. pass an array and iterate over the items in it

   ```
   function scripts(urls){
       window.setInterval(function (){
           for(var i=0,len = urls.length; i< len; i++){
               $.getScript( urls[i] );
            }
       },10000)
   }
   // pass an array
   scripts(['http://www.site1.com/1.jpg','http://www.site2.com/1.jpg']);
   ```
2. use the arguments keyword

   ```
   function scripts(){
       var urls = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       window.setInterval(function (){
           for(var i=0,len = urls.length; i< len; i++){
               $.getScript( urls[i] );
            }
       },10000)
   }

   scripts('http://www.site1.com/1.jpg','http://www.site2.com/1.jpg');
   ```

Comment: Above commenter has added an additional ".call" after the slice. Is there any difference ?

Comment: @user198989 yes, it is required. It was an oversight on my part. I have edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)*** object.

```
function scripts(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    window.setInterval(function (){
        // then use a loop for args.

    }, 1000)
}
```